# What is the simplest way to fire and forget a thread in c++ / Qt on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt

I'm writing an app that embeds multiple libVlc instances running simultaneously using Qt. There seems to be a bug in the vlc library where sometimes libvlc_media_player_stop deadlocks if called from the Qt's GUI thread. On one of the videolan forums, the accepted solution was to call the stop function from another thread. I'm looking for the least involved and not-too-ugly method to call stop from a different thread. I looked at using QThreadPool which is meant exactly for this kind of situations but in my particular case, it doesn't make the solution pretty.

Here's a piece of my code:

VlcWidget.h

```
    class VlcWidget : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    private:

        // State
        bool _isPlaying;

        // The streaming source, title and quality data
        VideoData _videoData;
        VIDEO_QUALITY _quality;

        // LibVlc related members
        libvlc_instance_t *_vlcInstance;
        libvlc_media_player_t *_vlcMediaPlayer;
        libvlc_media_t *_vlcMedia;
        int _vlcTrackID;
    }
```

VlcWidget.c

```
    void VlcWidget::Play()
    {
        if(_videoData.Source() != "" && !_isPlaying)
        {
            // Create a new media descriptor
            _vlcMedia = libvlc_media_new_location(
                          _vlcInstance,
                          _videoData.Source().toStdString().c_str());

            // Tell the user about incorrect URL
            if(_vlcMedia == NULL)
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this,
                                         _videoData.Title(),
                                         "Unable to open source Url.\nPlease check the source and try again.");
                return;
            }

            libvlc_media_player_set_media(_vlcMediaPlayer, _vlcMedia);
            libvlc_media_release(_vlcMedia);
            libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow(_vlcMediaPlayer, parentWidget()->winId());
            libvlc_media_player_play(_vlcMediaPlayer);
            _vlcTrackID = libvlc_audio_get_track(_vlcMediaPlayer);
            _isPlaying = true;
        }
    }

    void VlcWidget::Stop()
    {
        if(_isPlaying)
        {
            libvlc_media_player_stop(_vlcMediaPlayer);
            _vlcTrackID = -1;
            _isPlaying = false;
        }
    }
```

My solution using QthreadPool looked like:

```
    class AsyncVlcPlay : public QRunnable
    {
    private:
         // State
        bool *_isPlaying;

        // LibVlc related members
        libvlc_instance_t *_vlcInstance;
        libvlc_media_player_t *_vlcMediaPlayer;
        libvlc_media_t *_vlcMedia;
        int *_vlcTrackID;

    public:
        virtual void run();
    }
```

And AsyncVlcPlay::run() does exactly what VlcWidget::Play() does with simple locking added to it. And I'll also need a similar class for VlcWidget::Stop(). I don't like this solution because I shouldn't really need 2 new classes for what I'm trying to achieve. And worse than that is the fact that I'll have to pass VlcWidgets private members to another class' object.  I'm pretty sure there's an extremely simple way that I'm not aware of and hope that one of you guys can help me out here. Thanks!

(In fact, I don't really need VlcWidget::Play() to be on another thread, but I'd like to keep Play and Stop symmetric)

Comment: Maybe [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you're going to use QtConcurrent, I suggest you read this first: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/7942

Comment: As long as the basic functionality of QtConcurrent remains, which they say will be, my app should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my (part of) code for coupling SWI-Prolog syntax highlighting to Qt

```
// start highlighting, using SWI-Prolog syntax analyzer to collect structured data
//
void pqSource::startHighliter() {
    auto f = [](QString file, pqSyntaxData* psd) {
        SwiPrologEngine::in_thread _it;
        try {
            // ?? PlCall("consult", V(A(file)));
            qDebug() << "running syntax color on" << file << "thread" << CT;
            int rc = PlCall("syncol", PlTermv(A(file), PlTerm(psd)));
            qDebug() << "syncol" << rc;
        }
        catch(PlException e) {
            qDebug() << t2w(e);
        }
    };

    // collect structure asyncronously
    auto w = new QFutureWatcher<void>;
    connect(w, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(runHighliter()));

    // since could be a slow task, place a visual hint to what's going on...
    CenterWidgets((sd = new pqSyntaxData)->pgb = new QProgressBar(this));
    QTextCursor c = textCursor();
    c.movePosition(c.End);
    sd->pgb->setMaximum(c.position());
    connect(sd, SIGNAL(onProgress(int)), sd->pgb, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    sd->pgb->show();

    // run the Prolog snippet in background (hl pointer)
    w->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(f, file, sd));
}
```

I think you could be interested in the use of lambda...

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this problem with QThread. Its name is actually misleading as it's not actually a thread, but a thread controller and very easy to use.

Any class inherited from QObject can be moved to a thread and communication between threads can be done with the signal / slot mechanism. Therefore, you can do something like this: -

```
class VlcObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
        void Run();

    private slots;
        void StopVlc();
};
```

This class can contain all the Vlc objects / instances. You then create a thread controller object and move the VlcObject instance to the new thread: -

```
QThread* pThread = new QThread(this); // where this is a parent, running on the main thread
VlcObject* pVlcObj = new VlcObject;

pVlcObj->moveToThread(pThread);

// Note, this is Qt 5 connect style - Qt 4 connections also work
connect(pThread, &QThread::started, pVlcOj, &VlcObject::Run();

// Start the thread running
pThread->start();
```

Assuming QVlcWidget is a GUI class with a button called pStopVlc, you then call stop on the other thread's VlcObject by connecting the button to the VlcObject's StopVlc function: -

```
connect(pStopVlc, &QPushButton::released, pVlcObj, &VlcObject::StopVlc);
```

Alternatively, you could have StopVlc called when the thread quits and it is possible for the QThread to clean itself up when it stops: -

```
connect(pThread, &QThread::finished, pThread, &Qthread::deleteLater);
```

Comment: I love the part where you create a thread on the heap and forget all about it after connecting to the deleteLater slot! I had no idea you could do that (I'm only a week old in Qt yet).

Comment: And does ->moveToThread mean that everything that pVlcObj does in the future will be on the new thread? That is probably not what I want.

Comment: @Kulki you can add signals to pVlcObj and connect them to have it trigger a slot on another thread

Comment: @ratchetfreak - I'm not sure how you could force a slot to be called from another thread?

Comment: @Kulki in the example just add a signal to VlcObject and then do `connect(pVlcObj, &VlcObject::my_signal, this, &VlcWidget::listeningSlot)` after you do move to thread. Qt will automatically use a queued connection

Comment: @Kulki, the objects you decide to move to another thread depends on the overall architecture of your system and why you're using a different thread; often because something needs a considerable amount of time to process and you don't want to stall the main thread and GUI. You could quite easily justify keeping just the GUI on the main thread and move everything else to another. Note that multiple objects can be moved to that new thread. As for signals and slots, they're thread safe, so long as the correct connection type is made; the default connection (Auto) will usually work just fine.

Comment: @merlin069 Yes, I now understand (or I think I do) how the moveToThread would work and after a little thought I don't think I'd want to use it. My main concern is that moveToThread works at the instance level and not functional level. And I can't move the entire VlcWidget instances to a new thread because it has a bunch of buttons/widgets on it. And in order to move Stop() to a new thread, seems to me, I'll have to create another class that has just Stop in it. This is similar to my solution using QThreadPool. Please let me know if I've misunderstood something. Thanks!

Comment: "can't move the entire VlcWidget...it has a bunch of buttons/widgets on it" - this is the first problem that I'd worry about. Regardless of whether you use QThread, QConcurrent or anything else, I strongly advise you keep all GUI elements separate from everything else and communicate with GUI classes (windows / dialogs etc) via slots and signals. Without this, you'll likley come across other issues, such as the one you're now faced with in how to move the worker object to another thread.

Comment: I agree that the GUI should've been completely separate from the other logic. But, in my case the VLC instance has to be derived from QWidget and hence cannot be kept separate from the UI. And it all worked fine until I hit this VLC bug where vlc_stop, which is non-blocking, at times hits a deadlock when called from the gui thread. Let me know if there's another/better way to add the VLC player instance to a frame/layout without deriving from QWidget or any other Qt class.

Comment: Can't you wrap the members (_vlcInstance, _vlcMediaPlayer, _vlcMedia etc) in a class derived from QObject and place that in the VlcWidget; then in VlcWidget, create a thread and move the object to that thread to separate their functionality from VlcWidget?